# Read data from multiple excel files and use it in another excel for some calculations

Tags: excel, vba

i have data in multiple excel files (numbers). I need to use these data (no need to copy) and perform some calculations in another excel file. Could someone help me with macros to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question (do not comment), and provide more info on kind of the data and the calculations result format.